# SpeedFan keeps my computer from hibernating

Tags: batch, hibernate, scheduled-tasks, speedfan

I want to do a batch script that will hibernate my PC everyday at 2AM. The script itself is working but the thing is that SpeedFan, a fan speed controller software keeps my computer from hibernating. I'm am sure that the problem comes form SpeedFan as whenever the software is not running, the computer hibernates as expected but when it is running, my screens will go black but fans are still running and my RGB keyboard won't turn off.

I run

- Windows 8.1 Professional 64 Bits
- AMD FX-8320
- GTX 780
- 16GB of RAM
- MSI 970A-G43
- My SpeedFan version is 4.5.1

Is there a way to fix this problem? Is this a know issue of SpeedFan? Can I shutdown the SpeedFan process from within the Batch script?

Answer (score 0):

Try

' taskkill /f /im speedfan.exe'
Before running hibernating script .

(Make sure "speedfan.exe" is the correct name of the process)

Comment: I tried `taskkill /f /im speedfan.exe` but Windows is unable to find the process. I manually check all of my running processes and it is in fact not there. After more research, I found that SpeedFan behaves more like a driver than like a normal process and that may be a SpeedFan.sys process running but unfortunately, no luck with that either : [file.net](http://www.file.net/process/speedfan.sys.html)